# Unit Testing Mail Queue on Laravel 5

Tags: php, email, queue, phpunit, laravel-5

I'm facing two situations that I would like to address / understand.

1st - How do I Unit Test Laravel's Mail Queue Class?

The code that I want to test is this:

```
// Create new customer record
$account = $this->create(['account_id' => $account->id]);

// Get email address to send welcome email.
$email = $data['email'];

// Email Subject
$subject = $this->word('emails.welcome.subject');

$this->mailQueue->queue('emails.welcome',
    ['some_data' => 'data'],
    function ($message) use ($email, $subject) {
        $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
    }, true);

return $account;
```

I would like to know where is the `shouldReceive` method that will work for me when using `Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue` class.

Right now I have this unit test for this:

```
/**
 * @tests
 */
public function it_should_sign_up_a_new_user() {   
    // MailQueue::shouldReceive() does not exist.

    list($account, $email) = $this->getAccountData();
    $request = array_merge($account, $email);
    $account['password'] = $this->hash($account['password']);

    $this->post('/signup', $request, $this->header)
        ->assertResponseOk()
        ->seeInDatabase('account', $account)
        ->seeInDatabase('email', $email);
}
```

---

2nd - Why Unit Test does not require `php artisan queue:listen` or `queue:work`?

Every time I run the Unit Test, the email gets dispatched even though I have no `queue:listen` running. I would like to understand how this awesome magic happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unittesting Laravel 5 Mail using Mock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120567/unittesting-laravel-5-mail-using-mock)

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs it looks like they recommend using `Mail::queue` . i.e.

```
Mail::queue('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

The Mail Facade has `shouldReceive` built into it so you should be able to do:

`Mail::shouldReceive('queue')->once()`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#queueing-mail